# Navigation Drawer Header background image consumes a lot of memory

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

so today I started configuring my Navigation drawer and I started by making the header.

the problem is whenever I include a background for the header the app raises it's memory consumption from 10,000K~12000K to 35000K~40000K on just starting without loading any data, I'm literally using an empty fragment.

so naturally when I start bringing the data which is some photos (my application have a part where it shows photos from external storage through a recycler view with Glide) the application goes crazy and Glide can't load anything because of low memory (the app jumps over 64000K after some scrolling into the recycler view)

I want to avoid using large heap option, that's why I want to know why the header background is consuming all this megabytes though its size is 32KB only, of type JPEG, and it's resolution is 1600X900 ? and how to avoid this memory expansion (how include the image properly as background/drawable) ?

my navigation drawer header code :

```
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="@drawable/navigation_header_bg">

    <com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/image_basic_label"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/ShapeAppearanceOverlay.App.CornerSize50Percent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_person"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/username_textview_header"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:text="@string/not_logged_in_header"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.29000002" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/email_textview_header"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:text="@string/no_email_header"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/username_textview_header"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.14999998" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[**my image link**](https://blog.sebastiano.dev/content/images/2019/07/1_l3wujEgEKOecwVzf_dqVrQ.jpeg)

[image: image properties]

Answer (score 1):

1. Its not just about size of the image. In Android, resolution of images can affect the performance of views, which may not be a problem for some android devices but cause issues in others.
   Try to lessen the width of the image to 800 and height in proportion using Paint(Windows) or a suitable Image viewer(in other platforms) by cropping.
2. And then rerun the app on your device and check
3. Also, if possible, kindly share your device name and model alongwith Android version.

Comment: this reading I've included in the post was from an actual Samsung old phone with api 18, after your answer I started some testing, I've tried using an actual OPPO phone with api 30, it used 95K without the background and 110K with the background, I've tried using a virtual pixel 4 with api 18, it used 35K without the background and 54K with the background

Comment: isn't 15MB~25MB of memory too much for a 32KB JPEG photo !!?, what if in the future when I reach the end of the application decided to use a bit some backgrounds wouldn't it consume more and more memory that it would explode, isn't there a way to avoid this ?

Comment: oh yes when I resized it to 800*450 it dropped down memory consumption on all devices by 10K to 15K.

Comment: Hope my solution helped you slightly. :) You have done a good job by monitoring memory consumption on several devices! (y) ya 15-20 MB is too much. Can you try an SVG to see if that helps reduce memory consumption?